# How to get useragent in controller magento?

Tags: magento

I need to get full infomation of user agent in controller magento. Is there the way to get it?

Answer (score 29):

```
Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent()
```

Internally it is just accessing `$_SERVER` as you would normally but also does some character encoding stuff. Using this way allows other modules/developers to modify the returned value, which makes it future proof.